# Empty data sending into MySQL, instead input value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have simple php/ajax/mysql chat. But unfortunately when I am sending form into database, php send off empty string to MySQL, how can I fix it ?

Here page.php code, with script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#messages").load('ajaxLoad.php');

  $("#userArea").submit(function(){
    $.post('ajaxPost.php', $('#userArea').serialize(), function(data){
        $("#messages").append('<div>'+data+'</div>');

    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div id="messages"></div>
    <form method="post" action="ajaxPost.php" id="userArea" style="margin: 0 auto; font-size: 23px; text-align: center;">
      <h1>Chat</h1>
      <input type="text" name="message" />
      <input type="submit" value="send!" />
    </form>    
</div>
<?php include_once('ajaxLoad.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('ajaxPost.php'); ?>
```

And ajaxPost.php:

```
<?php 
include_once('page.php');
include('config.php');

$message = $_POST['message'];

$db->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message1) VALUES ('$message')");

echo $message;
?>
```

If you run: `alert($('#userArea').serialize())` it will show you your message.

Comment: what output you get `echo "INSERT INTO messages(message1) VALUES ('$message')"` ?

Comment: try your query with : $db->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message1) VALUES ('".$message."')");

Comment: Also cross check that you have right column name and table name

Comment: echo "INSERT INTO messages(message1) VALUES ('$message')"
It print "1"

Comment: $db->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message1) VALUES ('".$message."')"); 
String still empty ...

Comment: Table and column names is correct 100%.

Comment: @BimBam There's no way that couldjust print "1". It has to print something that begins with `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL injection, and it will fail if `$message` contains any quotes. You should use a prepared statement, or at least escape the string before substituting into the SQL.

Comment: Good idea, but it still send empty string to mysql column ...

Comment: @Barmar  awww, if it will print, as you said, it will print string " INSERT INTO messages(message1) ..."

Comment: What does it show after `VALUES`? That's the most important part and you replaced it with `...`

Comment: @Barmar INSERT INTO messages(message1) VALUES ('')

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of these lines:

```
<?php include_once('ajaxLoad.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('ajaxPost.php'); ?>
```

These scripts are only supposed to be used from AJAX, you shouldn't execute them when just displaying the original form. When you execute them with `include()` there's nothing in `$_POST`, so you insert an empty message.

You haven't shown what's in `ajaxLoad.php`, but from the way you use it with `$("#messages").load()`, I doubt that it should be run with `include`.

I'm pretty sure that `ajaxPost.php` works correctly when you call it with `$.post()`, and the empty rows are coming from the `include_once()`.

I don't think it should prevent the insert, but you also shouldn't have

```
include_once('page.php');
```

in `ajaxPost.php`.

Comment: When you look at the AJAX request in DevTools Network tab, do you see the message in the parameters?